# Recognizing infinite sets in set theory

Tags: fractions

I am learning set theory and one of my questions was this:

**Is the set of fractions between 0 and 1 an infinite set?**

I initially thought the answer was yes, but one of this possible answer confused me:

**The statement is false; the set of all real numbers between 0 and 1, which includes both fractions and irrational numbers, is an infinite set, but the set of fractions alone is a finite set.**

Could someone please help me rationalize whether this is true or not?

Comment: The statement in bold is false: the set $\{1/1,1/2,1/3,1/4,\dots\}$ is a subset of the set of fractions between $0$ and $1$, and it is clearly infinite. Therefore, the set of fractions between $0$ and $1$ is infinite. (The set of irrational numbers between $0$ and $1$ is also infinite.)

Comment: In general, one way to recognise a set $X$ is infinite, is to ask whether you can construct an injective map $\mathbb{N}\to X$, if so then it has at least the cardinality of the natural numbers

Comment: If you substitute "infinite set" with "uncountable set" and "finite set" with "countable set", then the statement makes sense.

Comment: @Morgan Rodgers ... I am taking Contemporary College Mathematics, and this specific question (and possible answer)  was in my Set Theory homework. Like I said, I originally thought the answer was infinite, but this possible answer was so weird, I couldn't wrap my mind around it and it made me doubt everything. :)